# How to use BackGroundWorker in class file?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

My program.cs calls the mdi parent frmMain. frmMain then opens different child forms based on user action.

All the processing logic is written in BusinessLogic.cs. frmMain at load calls the methods of BusinessLogic.cs to initially populate the data. The child forms too call BusinessLogic to fetch data and process it. I'd like to do all this through a BackGroundWorker ie the frmMain calls the (say) StartBGWorker() method of BusinessLogic.cs and this method creates a backgroundworker for this specific call, calls the Do_work event, does the fetching & processing and closes when done.

I'm at a loss about how to create the instance and the events for backgroundworker. So how exactly do I use backgroundworker in a class file?

Edit: Maybe my logic is wrong and I should add a BGW to each form that calls BusinessLogig.cs. Then whenever I call a method of BusinessLogic I can do so through backgroundworker. Would this be a better implementation?

Edit2: Feel a bit idiotic about my doubt now that I found a way. I just created a public static method with the initialize code of BGW in BusinessLogic. Now whenever I need to do processing I first call this method from my forms. 
I'd like to know if my implementation of BGW is standard or is there any way to improve the design.

Comment: Does this mean that different forms pass different parameters (different tasks) to your `BackgroundLogic`? Or do they all wait for the same set data to be ready?

Comment: All forms need different data. The methods for that are in BL. When a form calls BL it would call the relevant method.

Answer (score 3):

Include:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Define it in your class:

```
private BackgroundWorker BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Initialize it:

```
BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
BackgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted );
```

To start it:

```
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The usage is exactly the same as you know from Windows Forms.

Comment: sounds a bit stupid but that exactly was my issue. Where to initialize it in a class file? Finally I created a public static method in BusinessLogic with the initialize code for BGW in it. Now before calling the BGW related method from my forms I first call the method with initialize code.

Comment: If the BackgroundWorker itself is static or instance-agnostic, aren't other methods of your class static? Because if so, you could just initialize the BackgroundWorker in the static constructor. Static constructor fires automatically just before your first reference to the static class (before you call any of its method for the first time, for example) so it would save you having to remember calling your method beforehand.

Comment: Whenever I use BackgroundWorker I initialize it once in the constructor of my view model, static or instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the Parallel Task Library. There you can start,link and sync asynchronous operations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

You could also inject an object with an delegate, event,  Actio which can be triggered from within the new task to report the progress

for example

You Implement an entity like this

```
  public class TaskData
    {
        private Action<int> Callback { get; private set; }

        public TaskData(Action<int> callbackAction)
        {
            this.Callback = callbackAction;

        }

        public void TriggerCallBack(int percentageComplete)
        {
            Action<int> handler = Callback;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(percentageComplete);
            }
        }
    }
```

Than you create a Task with this entity as parameter

```
TaskData data = new TaskData((percentage)=> Console.WriteLine(percentage + "% completed"));

            Task myTask = new Task(new Action<object>((para)=>
            {
                ((TaskData)para).TriggerCallBack(4);
            }

            ),data);

            myTask.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();
```

PS: The code is just a quick and dirty hack. feel free to improve it :-)

Answer (score -5):

Please don't use `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`, create your own threads instead and implement events if you want to report progress. I had so much bugs with it that I can freely say that it should never ever be used.

Comment: Very bad advice - maybe you could post a question about the "bugs" you encountered with BackgroundWorker, and you might change your mind...

Comment: As far as I remember, BackgroundWorker is just a wrapper around ThreadPool. This is supposed to offer better performance, since ThreadPool removes the overhead associated with spawning new threads (as the name itself indicates, it maintains a pool of threads to which work can be dispatched). Threading is very bug-prone in its own right, but I haven't heard about BackgroundWorker being buggy by itself.

Comment: Restarting it doesn't always work, on long runs doesn't report that it has finished its operation, can't remember all the bugs (or their exact manifestations) at once since it was about 2 years since I've used it for the last time, but I remember that I lost a lot of time fixing the damn thing.